# badblocks fails to spot corrupting disk controller

Tags: hard-disk, corruption, badblocks

I have file corruption problem on a HDD (the SDD in the same computer works fine):

```
for i in {1..10}; do
  dd if=/dev/zero of=zeroes_$i.dat bs=512 count=4M
done
md5sum zeroes_*
```

yields the correct checksum a981130cf2b7e09f4686dc273cf7187e for some files, but often another one. `grep` confirms that it finds non-zero characters in some files.
So there is definitely something fishy here (based on swapping hardware with another computer, I suspect more the controller than the disk, but this is not the topic of this question).
This is «reproducible» in the sense that there are always several zeroes_$i.dat files with a failing checksum.

Now the strange part: `badblocks -wvs -b 32768 -c 2048` report no error even after testing 4 patterns.
What could cause badblocks to fail to find corrupting IO? The thing that puzzles me is that `md5sum` doesn't read the same thing that `dd` wrote, while `badblocks` does read back exactly what it wrote. Where could that come from?

Edit: thanks dominix for your idea. IIUC, there could be a faulty cache in the controller causing incorrect checksums, while badblocks would have a mechanisme to disable caching (like writing the whole disk before reading back) and actually test the disk rather than the controller, correct?

Comment: What does `dmesg` tell you?

Comment: it may be hardware related. What kind of controller are you using ? does it have settings like write-back write-through ?

Comment: Have you tried to identify the specific non-zero blocks in the files? What happens if you read/write those directly? I'd rather suspect flakey RAM than a problem with the disk controller. If you are reasonable sure it's the disk, also have a look at the SMART values.

Answer (score 0):

The cache I mention in my edit could also be the cache managed by the OS, a cache which resides in RAM. The following scenario would also explain the symptoms:

- some RAM portion with a far address is faulty. OS is loaded in the beginning of the RAM and thus unaffected
- later when reading/writing large amount of data to disk, all the RAM is eventually used, including the faulty portion
- badblocks uses only a small amount of RAM (unlikely to be faulty) and disables the OS cache for its disk IO, so it's unaffected
- md5sum, on the other hand, when "reading" the disk, is actually reading the data cached by the OS, which is sometimes faulty.

Thus, for other readers having the same symptoms as me: run `memtest`.